# Remove all specific characters from a string

Tags: node.js

I want to remove all characters in a string excpet this characters `> < + - []  , .` , how can I do this without using `for` loops?

```
var dontRemove = '><+-[],.';
var myStr = 'hello world <. noder neder'
```

```
function filterString(string) {
    var result = '';
    for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index++) {
        if (['>', '<', '+', '-', '[', ']', ',', '.'].includes(string[index])) {
            result += string[index];
        } 
    }
    return result;
}

let x = filterString('hello world <>dassa>?.');
console.log(x);
```

**Excepted Output:**

```
var myStr = 'hello<?.,d[]?2dasdx.';
var result = filterString(myStr);
console.log(result);
>>> <.,[].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the replace() method with regular expressions for this.

```
var myStr = 'hello world <. noder neder'
var x = myStr.replace(/[^<>\+\-\[\]\,\.]/g, "");
console.log(x);
```

This replaces all the characters not specified in the regex with an empty string by using the '^' symbol in the beginning of the square brackets. Most of these characters need to be escpaed using \ because they are used as a part of regular expressions. The g at the end makes sure the replacement is applied globally and not just on the first occurence.

Comment: You don't need to use \ (backslash) for every character in the regex, but only for the characters `-`, `[`, `]`.

Comment: `+` and `.` would also require escaping as they are used in regex for "one or more of the previous expression" and "any character" respectively

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all characters except the one you mentioned in the question using the `replace()` method.

Try the code below.

```
const regex = /[^><+\-,.\[\]]/g;
var str = '!@#><+-[],.%^&hello world <. noder neder';

let result = str.replace(regex, "");
console.log(result);
```

The above code will output: `><+-[],.<.`.

For reference, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: It does not solved my problem, because I still have characters that I don't want them to be. As I said, I want to remove **anything** in the String except those characters: `><+-[],.`

Comment: My bad. I inferred it wrong. I've updated my answer. Please check once.

Answer (score 1):

## Using [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

This is going to be very similar to your approach but uses the built-in `.filter` method on arrays. In addition, it converts the lookup to a Set to guarantee `O(n)` performance:

```js
function filterString(keep, string) {
    const allowed = new Set(keep.split(""));
    
    return string
      .split("")                         // get character array
      .filter(char => allowed.has(char)) // only leave allowed
      .join("");                         // convert back to string
}

let x = filterString("><+-[],.", 'hello<?.,d[]?2dasdx.');
console.log(x);
```

## Regular Expression

This is an alternative way to implement this. It relies on creating a regular expression dynamically and only keeping anything it *doesn't* match, for which a negated character class is used:

```js
function filterString(keep, string) {
    const allowedCharacterSet = keep
      .split("")                // get characters
      .map(char => `\\${char}`) // escape
      .join("");                // join back
     
    return string.replace(new RegExp(`[^${allowedCharacterSet}]`, "g"), "");
}

let x = filterString("><+-[],.", 'hello<?.,d[]?2dasdx.');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: The output only returns `<>>.`. I want to remove anything except: `><+-[],.`

Comment: @harabatahat the only characters from that list are `<`, `>`, `>`, and `.`. There is no `+` nor `-` nor `?`, nor `,` in the example string you've given. Also, it matches what your code produces, so I'm not sure what output you're looking for instead.

Comment: @harabatahat OK, then what is the output you expect, then?

Comment: Your function does work now. I up voted the answer.

Comment: @harabatahat I didn't change anything before your comment. As you commented, I only updated the sample string from one to the other. The logic is still the same in both cases.

Comment: Then it's my mistake, sorry.